# Import own files in python

Tags: python, import, module

Imagine a main.py.
I have the following structure

```
├── main.py
├── moduleX
│   ├── setup.py
│   ├── submoduleA
│   │   └── fileA.py
│   │   └── fileB.py
│   ├── submoduleC
│   │   └── fileC.py
```

Main calls moduleX.setup and setup needs to call functions from submodules A and B.

However moduleX.setup is unable to find the submodules and I don't know how to import them

So it goes like this:
in main.py

```
import moduleX.setup
```

in setup.py

```
from submoduleA import fileA
from submoduleA import fileB
import submoduleC
```

and all submodules and files are not found.

All subfolders have empty **init**.py files. I am not sure how to fill them, seems like a recursive problem.

I tried adding moduleX to sys.path
I tried prpending moduleX everywhere
I tried using .. and .

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: try adding this file into each sub-directory: `__init__.py` and fill the file like: `from .fileC import *`

Comment: thanks @Hanz . I have all subdirectories with __init__py files already

Answer (score 1):

Python always uses the relative path to the file you are executing.

```
from moduleX.submoduleA import fileA
from moduleX.submoduleA import fileB
import moduleX.submoduleC
```

should work

Comment: I ended up having to do weird things. But yes this was the first thing. I modified the __init__.py files to include
import moduleX.submoduleA
from moduleX.submoduleA import fileA
and sometimes I need to calle fileA as
submoduleA.submoduleA.fileA.
very weird, but it worked.
Thank you

Comment: A good way to approach the problem is by making each subdirectory a "lib". Create a __init__.py that includes all the files or classes you need, and based on this import you can access sub functions or classes. That is the way you are used to doing when importing numpy, pandas, ...